# How to fix PNG positioning in IE 6-8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, png, internet-explorer-6

I am running Thesis 1.8.5 on the latest version of Wordpress and I can not seem to fix the positioning of my headshot PNG image in IE 6-8, seen here www.texashomeloanpro.com. Although the PNG image looks great in Chrome and Safari, in IE the image is pushed slightly to the right leaving a white box in its place.

Here is the simple CSS that I have right now:

```
#new-sidebar-1 img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;}
```

I have tried using different margins, removing the float, adding 'diplay: inline', and even this manual fix http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/, but nothing seems to remove the white box and move the PNG image to the right place in IE.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 1):

You've got some extraneous markup:

```
<img class="mike_jones_photo"/>
<a href="http://www.texashomeloanpro.com/contact-us/">
    <img src="http://www.texashomeloanpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/20130516_170510.002-120x150.png"/>
</a>
```

Note the extra `<img>` tag on the first line. It doesn't have a `src` attribute set. IE makes room for this empty image, while other browsers may ignore it.

You probably want something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.texashomeloanpro.com/contact-us/">
    <img class="mike_jones_photo" src="http://www.texashomeloanpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/20130516_170510.002-120x150.png"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Bryson, you have no idea how much time I have spent trying to fix this issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @gsifers Happy to help. Can you please mark this as answered?